# Change Angular 2/4 Material default styles for "md-menu"

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to change default Angular Material styles of `md-menu`. The problem is the Angular Material generates elements dynamically and I can't get access to them from my HTML.

Here is my DOM:

[image]

And here is my component HTML (`md-menu` generates that DOM):

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <img src="../../../images/avatar-default.png" class="avatar" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu" />

  <md-menu #userMenu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item>{{username}}</button>
    <button md-menu-item>Log Out</button>
  </md-menu>
</md-toolbar>
```

I know that I can get access to that `div` (selected on the picture) from global styles using `.mat-menu-content {...}`, but it will affect other elements with such classes. And I'm unable to set styles to this div from component CSS, because the element is outside component scope. So I'm trying to find the way to change styles of this element from component CSS and without affecting other elements with such style.

If there is a way to implement it, please, let me know.

Comment: What kind of style change you want to apply to `md-menu`?

Comment: @Nehal, remove paddings at first, then change background colors, may be something else...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if using `/deep/` is an option for you.

> Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's
>   own template.
>
> Use the `/deep/` selector to force a style down through the child
>   component tree into all the child component views. The `/deep/` selector
>   works to any depth of nested components, and it applies to both the
>   view children and content children of the component.

[Doc](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deep)

component.css:

```
/deep/ .mat-menu-content {
    background: skyblue !important;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

/deep/ .mat-menu-item {
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/s91qeAlg3F3eexeFsjyK?p=preview)

Comment: /deep/ is deprecated now. In Angular, ViewEncapsulation.Emulated is the default option which means, it tries to narrow-down the scope of the affect by adding surrogate keys to the host-element etc. One option could be is to add below css. But mind, this ng-deep will also be deprecated soon. Have to wait to know the alternative! https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

   ::ng-deep .mat-menu-content {}

Answer (score 2):

Described in the picture below,[Maybe this doc would help](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api)
[image]

Comment: Seems like it's an answer. But I'm totally new to Angular, can you please provide an example, how to use this `@Input`?

Comment: @Commercial Suicide Sorry for being late, answer upstairs was awesome, this as an  alternative  [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/i3TO4YtRj95gsLUClTVz?p=preview)