# How to customize Angular-Material slide toggle

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I need to customize the colour, height and width of the `mat-slide-toggle`:

```
<mat-slide-toggle class="" [color]="color" [checked]="checked"   [disabled]="disabled"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

Comment: Hello @Murugan C, what did you try, what is blocking you?

Comment: You can also find some information here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50838843/1475378

Answer (score 0):

You can override the inner classes of mat-slide-toggle (.mat-slide-toggle-thumb, .mat-slide-toggle-bar) to customize their color, height and width.
Add these overrides to style.scss if you need it through your app, or to the css of your current component if the style needs to be scoped